# not able to use a string variable inside AdminApp.update() function

Tags: websphere, jython-2.7

C:\IBM_Thinclient_DEV>wsadmin.bat -lang jython -host traj-d-was01 -port 8879 -f Auto-deployments/Jython/UpdateApplicationSingleFile.py usergroups.yaml

WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node ******Manager01 using SOAP connector; The type of process is: DeploymentManager

WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: "[usergroups.yaml]"

WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "Auto-deployments/Jython/UpdateApplicationSingleFile.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:

Traceback (innermost last):

(no code object) at line 0

File "", line 17

```
   AdminApp.update('api-docs', 'file', '[-operation addupdate -contents C:/IBM_Thinclient_DEV/Auto-deployments/ear/swagger-spec/' +filename '-contenturi api-docs.war\yaml\' +filename ']')

                                                                                                                                            ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#####UpdateApplicationSingleFile.py######

import os.path

import sys

filename=sys.argv[0]

print "filename = " +filename

AdminApp.update('api-docs', 'file', '[-operation addupdate -contents C:/IBM_Thinclient_DEV/Auto-deployments/ear/swagger-spec/' +filename '-contenturi api-docs.war\yaml' +filename ']')

AdminApp.update('api-docs', 'file', '[-operation addupdate -contents C:/IBM_Thinclient_DEV/Auto-deployments/ear/swagger-spec/' +filename '-contenturi api-docs.war\yaml' +filename ']')

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `+` symbols to build your string connecting the string literal and variable parts.

So instead of:

```
AdminApp.update('api-docs', 'file', '[-operation addupdate -contents C:/IBM_Thinclient_DEV/Auto-deployments/ear/swagger-spec/' +filename '-contenturi api-docs.war\yaml' +filename ']')
```

it should look more like

```py
AdminApp.update('api-docs', 'file', '[-operation addupdate -contents C:/IBM_Thinclient_DEV/Auto-deployments/ear/swagger-spec/' + filename + ' -contenturi api-docs.war\yaml' + filename + ']')
```

Note besides the missing `+` signs I also added a space *before* `-contenturi`, because unless your 'filename' variable already includes its own space, this value would blur together with the "-contents ..." parameter value.

### LINKS

Some general helpful links on wsadmin+Jython:

- [introduction to wsadmin jython](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=scripting-using-wsadmin-jython)
- [PyDev for Eclipse IDE](https://www.pydev.org) - though you might need to use an older version like [v9.3.0](https://www.pydev.org/update_sites/9.3.0/) to use the Jython shipped with WebSphere.
- [wsadminlib library](https://github.com/wsadminlib/wsadminlib)